# How can I set the output resistance of a current source in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

[image]

I want to make output resistance of NMOS, PMOS, I1, I2 to 100k ohms. I set NMOS and PMOS lambda to 0.1, which makes ro = VA / ID = 100k ohms. How can Imake that independent current source output resistance to 100k ohms? I am using LTspice.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to make the output impedance of the current source 100 kOhms? If  so then just add a 100k Ohms resistance in parallel with the current source.

Comment: I tried it, but if I add a resistor in parallel with the current source, additional current flow to the drain of nmos, which makes ro smaller.

Comment: Maybe not related but your sine wave is set to 100millihertz. You need to use `meg` for mega. `M` and `m` both mean milli in SPICE.

Comment: @Son, if adding a resistor in parallel causes a problem in your circuit, then adding an output resistance to the current source will do the same thing.

Comment: @Son `lambda` should be a positive number, even in the PMOS model statement.  Also in the PMOS `.model` statement you need to specify the flag `pchan`.  So, it should look like this in total:  `.model PMOS VDMOS(pchan lambda=0.1)`